# RoR looking for column I've removed using migration command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema

Good day.
I'm new to ruby and I've tried to build a simple post form with nested "links" field.

E.g:

```
*****
TITLE
*****
POST
****

LINK - 1
LINK - 2
.
.
LINK - N 
****
```

Using 3 migration files I've got the following schema file

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130827060014) do

  create_table "links", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "link"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

the first 2 migration file are create table, when I've created the table for links I've also added post_id column.
Now I've decided to remove this column using the following command:

```
$->rails g migration remove_field_name_from_links post_id:links
$->rake db:migrant
```

The "new" controller for post looks like this

```
def new
    @new_post = Post.new
    3.times {@new_post.links.build}
end
```

The problem is that even though that column doesn't exist any more it appears the system is still looking for it as I get the following error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: links.post_id: SELECT "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE "links"."post_id" = ?
```

this is the view file:

```
<h1> <%= @post.title %></h1>
<p> <%= @post.body %></P>
<ul>
    <%= for links in @post.links do %>
        <li>
            <%= links.link %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

any ideas?

Comment: can you show you links controller...?

Comment: The links are nested inside the post, I don't have separate controller for them. I've made the following changes to the post model though. has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :links

Comment: check whether you have removed the "removed_field" from attr_accessible in the Links Model.

Comment: I'm using RoR 4, there's no attr_accessible at this version. when I did tried to add  "attr_accessible :link"   I've got the following error "`attr_accessible` is extracted out of Rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one."

Comment: I don't understand. You removed association's foreign key (post_id) from table and you still expect this association to work?

Comment: I removed it because I don't want to use this key.

Comment: But you still want your association, don't you? So how do you want foreign key for this association to be named?

Comment: To be more specific I believe that the problem is that it expect the "post_id" instead of just "id". and even though I've removed that column and it is not part of the schema any more it still looks for it.

Comment: Ok where does this error point?

Comment: I get this error whenever I try to "show" the post this is the line it points to: <%= for links in @post.links do %> the error I get is this one "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: links.post_id: SELECT "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE "links"."post_id" = ?
"

Comment: Paste the contents of your view to which the error points.

Comment: I've added it to the main question, The controller for show is   @post = Post.find(params[:id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all contents of `ul` tag listing your post's links will probably fix your error. Since you don't want `post_id` column in `links` table, I guess you also don't want this association. So, when you are done with removing this, remove also this association from your model and remove proper calls (for example `3.times {@new_post.links.build}`) from controllers.

The error occurs because when you have an association, Rails expect `links` table to have `post_id` column. Since you removed this column, it gives an error.